# props in not passing value to Child Component in React

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-props, setstate

I am developing a simple food app.
Firstly, it will show dishDetails in **MenuComponent**
and **onClick** it will pass **Id** of a selected dish to a function named as
**getDish(dishdetail)**
Here i want to send **props or state** to my **CartComponent** where it will show  details of selected Dish.

**Problem-1**
Props is not passing to Cart (undefined value)
but dishdetail name,id is showing if i do console.log in **MenuComponent**

How i can pass props/state to Cart kindly guide me.

```
//Here im binding my function

    class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getDish = this.getDish.bind(this);
  }




//This is my getDish function(in which i want to send props to Cart)
    getDish(dishDetail) {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            
            <Cart dishdetail={dishDetail}/>  **//undefined in Cart**
            {console.log({dishDetail.name})} **//it is working perfectly**
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
```

**Working Fine**

From Where I am sending data onClick function

```
<button
    onClick={() => this.getDish(this.props.dishes[index])}
  ></button>
```

Comment: because every component has it's lifecycle and lifecycle run when you either change state or re render component  and here you are not doing either so you need to consider doing it via state set your dishdetail in state and then pass the state variable as props

Comment: i did this .but setState is also not working in my case

Comment: Kindly guide me through code .how  i can do it?

Comment: How does the `Cart` component look?

Comment: First of all move your code inside render function i mean the code which you are returning via getDish function if you want to hide it initially you can apply some condition and then inside getDish function just setState for your dishdetail and pass the state variable via props when you do setState it will automatically run the render function and thus you child component will get refreshed

Answer (score 0):

All components should be rendered from render method. And there behaviour can be controlled using state.

// class Menu

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dishDetail: null
        };
        this.getDish = this.getDish.bind(this);
    }

    getDish(selectedDish) {
        this.setState({
            dishDetail: selectedDish
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <button onClick={() => this.getDish(this.props.dishes[index]])}>Click Me</button>
                {/*Cart is called from render and value passed from state*/}
                <Cart dishdetail={this.state.dishDetail}/> 
            </>
        );
    }
```

And your cart class will be re-rendered with your new data

```
class Cart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {
        console.log('cart', this.props);
        return (
          <div>You added {this.props.dishdetail} to cart</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: as method you mentioned above..is taking all the dishes Id in a single state not a selected Dish Id.Kindly guide more precisely

Comment: It is taking single dish id in the state, which changes dynamically on button click. Also, do you have multiple buttons to add to cart (one for each dish)?

Comment: I am Sending you complete MenuComponent in which i want to get Particular dish Id and pass it to CartComponent(Child component of Menu) like a Ecommerce website.Where we will order a item and it appears on Cart.
Also i do some changes i code.Please guide me i wasted my week on this error or bug